# running in the mornings

Tags: running

I have been running now for 2 months and completed a 10km training plan, and I love it. My wife works evening though and u don't go running until about 9.30pm (after dynamic warmups). Now I'm adding some hills to my training plan next, and some beginners hills where I live are off road and dark at the time I have been running.

My question is I want to switch my hills to early morning. I'm scratching my head about what I should be eating and how long before the morning run I should eat then leave? Any advice from fellow early risers?

Edit:

I'm following the BUPA 10Km advanced plan (after doing basic and immediate). My only goals are to increase my pace over 10Kms

http://www.bupa.co.uk/health-information/directory/r/running-programme-10km

Comment: Personally I think a lot of this will come down to personal preference. While no one wants to eat a huge breakfast before a long hot run, some people like a bit of food and others would rather run on an empty stomach. Your energy comes largely from stored glucose from the day before; what you eat in the morning isn't factoring in much (from a morning-run-energy point of view).

Comment: This is a question that is highly individual specific. There are also other questions about when to eat before running, such as: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/should-i-eat-before-my-run